# How to convert a location on football pitch to coordinates on rectangle?

Tags: coordinates, geo

I have 4 points of football pitch (corner points):

`P1(lat, lon, alt)`, `P2(lat, lon, alt)`, `P3(lat, lon, alt)`, `P4(lat, lon, alt)`.

and a location on the pitch:

`L(lat, lon, alt)`

I want to convert `L(lat, lon, alt)` to `L(x, y)` on a rectangle with size of `(W, H)`.

How to implement this conversion function? (I preferred C# language but implementation language is not important)

The following image describes my problem (I don't know how to implement the `Function` box):

[image]

Comment: What does the aerial photo have to do with this problem?  What you've described appears to be a straightforward rectilinear transformation -- linear algebra.

Comment: @Prune The aerial photo shows 4+1 points in `Geographic coordinate system`.

Comment: What programmatic input comes from the photo.  You described the problem as having (lat, long, alt) coordinates, which seems to leave the photo entirely out of the processing.  The altitude is immaterial, and you have a simple linear transformation ... no?

Comment: @Prune The aerial photo just describes the problem and signature of conversion function should be like this: `void Function(double p1lat, double p1lon, double p1alt, double p2lat, double p2lon, double p2alt, double p3lat, double p3lon, double p3alt, double p4lat, double p4lon, double p4alt, double Llat, double Llon, double Lalt, int width, int height, out int x, out int y)`

Comment: (1) Why is the altitude part of the inupt?  (2) Why is this a long sequence of `double` instead of a pair of points (opposite corners will define the pitch)?  (3) Where do the target `W, H` dimensions come in?  (4) Where are you stuck with the linear transformation?

Comment: @Prune (1) altitude provided for more accurate results, the implementation of conversion function may be does not use altitude. (2) sequence of `double` or pair of points can be used, the implementation of function is important for me (3) `W, H` can be any value for example valid values are: `W=110`, `H=75` (because 
 football pitch 110m x 75m)

Comment: I guess, on the image, `P4` should be `(0,H)`, not `(W,H)`?

Comment: @TeWu Yes, It is correct. Thank you :)

Comment: There are for example libs like OpenCV that can help you here, the perspective of the image will be different depending on location of the camera and the type of lens being used that will affect the image..

Comment: @AmirSaniyan Is my answer solving your problem?

Comment: @TeWu Thanks you for your answer

Comment: @AmirSaniyan I'm glad I was able to help :) I had a great time figuring this out, so thanks for asking an interesting question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, because output coordinates are 2D, I'm going to assume that we can get rid of altitude information from input coordinates. So input data consist of four points defining the input rectangle:

`P1(lat, lon)`, `P2(lat, lon)`, `P3(lat, lon)`, `P4(lat, lon)`

and dimensions of the output rectangle: `w`, `h`.

I'm also going to ignore the curvature of the Earth (football pitch is small enough). With those assumptions we can implement the conversion function, by performing affine transformation. It would be wasteful to create transformation matrix each time we want to perform a transformation. For that reason we need two functions: first one to create the transformation matrix (called only once), and the second one that will use that matrix to perform transformation itself (called possibly many times, one time for each point we want to transform), something like:

```
tm = createTransformationMatrix(P1, P2, P4, w, h)
inPoint = (200, 50)
outPoint = transform(inPoint, tm)
```

Note that we only need three of four input points to unambiguously define a rotated rectangle in 2D euclidean space.

Here is the implementation of `createTransformationMatrix` and `transform` functions:

```js
const run = function() {

  // Creates transformation matrix to transform
  // from rectangle somewhere in 2D space with coordinates p0, px, pi, py
  // to rectangle with coordinates (x=0, y=0), (x=w, y=0), (x=w, y=h), (x=0, y=h).
  // Note that: p0 is mapped to (x=0, y=0)
  //            px is mapped to (x=w, y=0)
  //            py is mapped to (x=0, y=h)
  const createTransformationMatrix = function(p0, px, py, w, h) {
    // Translate px and py by p0 - pxt and pyt are px and py vectors in coordinate system in which p0 is at the origin
    const pxt = {
      x: px.x - p0.x,
      y: px.y - p0.y,
    };
    const pyt = {
      x: py.x - p0.x,
      y: py.y - p0.y,
    };

    // Create transformation matrix, which is inverse of transformation matrix that:
    //   1. Transforms (x=0, y=0) to (x=p0.x,             y=p0.y)
    //   2. Transforms (x=1, y=0) to (x=p0.x + pxt.x / w, y=p0.y + pxt.y / w)
    //   3. Transforms (x=0, y=1) to (x=p0.x + pyt.x / h, y=p0.y + pyt.y / h)
    return Matrix.invert3([
      [pxt.x / w, pyt.x / h, p0.x],
      [pxt.y / w, pyt.y / h, p0.y],
      [0        , 0        , 1   ],
    ]);
  };

  const transform = function(point, transformationMatrix) {
    // Convert point to homogeneous coordinates
    const inputVector = [
      [point.x],
      [point.y],
      [1],
    ];
    // Transform inputVector
    const outputVector = Matrix.multiply(transformationMatrix, inputVector);
    // Convert outputVector back to cartesian coordinates and return
    return {
      x: outputVector[0][0] / outputVector[2][0],
      y: outputVector[1][0] / outputVector[2][0],
    };
  };


  const w = 220;
  const h = 115;
  const p1 = {x:-79, y:80 };
  const p2 = {x:9,   y:-96};
  const p3 = {x:55,  y:-72};
  const p4 = {x:-34, y:105};

  const tm = createTransformationMatrix(p1, p2, p4, w, h);
  const inPoint  = {x: 200, y: 50};
  const outPoint = transform(inPoint, tm);
  console.log(`(${inPoint.x}, ${inPoint.y}) --[transform]--> (${outPoint.x}, ${outPoint.y})`);
}


//// Matrix ////
const Matrix = {};

Matrix.scale = (s, m) => m.map(x => Array.isArray(x) ? Matrix.scale(s, x) : s * x);

Matrix.multiply = function(a, b) {
  const aNumRows = a.length, aNumCols = a[0].length;
  const bNumRows = b.length, bNumCols = b[0].length;
  const m = new Array(aNumRows);
  for (let r = 0; r < aNumRows; ++r) {
    m[r] = new Array(bNumCols);
    for (let c = 0; c < bNumCols; ++c) {
      m[r][c] = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < aNumCols; ++i)
        m[r][c] += a[r][i] * b[i][c];
    }
  }
  return m;
};

Matrix.invert3 = function(m) {
  const [[a, b, c],
         [d, e, f],
         [g, h, i]] = m;
  const det = a*(e*i - f*h) - b*(d*i - f*g) + c*(d*h - e*g);
  return Matrix.scale(1/det, [
    [e*i - f*h, c*h - b*i, b*f - c*e],
    [f*g - d*i, a*i - c*g, c*d - a*f],
    [d*h - e*g, b*g - a*h, a*e - b*d],
  ]);
};
//////////////

run();
```

I've included all the matrix processing logic, so that this code snippet is self contained, but I would suggest you to instead use some linear algebra library for matrix processing.

I've also made **[a more visual demo](https://jsfiddle.net/TeWu/9fat6guz/9/)**.

Comment: If you want to learn more about linear algebra, definitely check out the ["Essence of linear algebra" by 3Blue1Brown](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab) on YouTube. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P2LTAUO1TdA) is especially relevant in context of this question.